# Mocking Mybatis Mapper Not working in Spring boot integration tests

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to mock my batis mapper.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApiApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test-application.properties")
public class SpringGlue {

  @TestConfiguration
  public static class TestConfig {


    @Bean
    @Primary
    ProductMapper productMapper(){

      ProductMapper productMapper = mock(ProductMapper.class);

      doAnswer(i -> {
        String id = i.getArgument(0);
        return Product.builder().id(id).name(id + "hello").build();
      }).when(productMapper).getProductById(any());



      return productMapper;
    }

   

  }
}
```

But this is not getting mocked

```
nsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productMapper'

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(SqlSessionDaoSupport.java:122)
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:73)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
```

Comment: Apparently, Spring is trying to create the `ProductMapper` bean in the standard way probably because there is some misconfiguration. The executable [demo project](https://github.com/dldiehl77/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-62409666) created by another user shows you the entire setup. The `@MockBean` test will pass if you changed the version of 'mybatis-spring-boot-starter' from 2.1.3 to 2.1.4. `@TestConfiguration` + `@Autowired` should also work if you prefer that way. If you still need help, please share a similar executable project on your GitHub repo.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot 3, try mybatis-spring-boot-starter-2.3.0-SNAPSHOT.